# Storing data into the blockchain

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

Writing a DApp where it stores data into a "blockchain". I'm trying to write this in solidity but i don't understand how to store it into a "blockchain". Am i able to do it like this? Would it be safe to store data just like that?

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract database{
struct Data{
    uint index;
    uint value;
}

Data[] public Datas;

  function AddData(uint _index, uint _data) public {
      Datas.push(Data(_index, _data));
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, your code looks fine.

Comment: to make it more secure i can add hashes on every block of data? cause im trying to make a database to store the data. Would i be able to change that particular data in the array?

Comment: What do you mean by "to make it more secure?" And sure, you could change the data if you write a function that does that.

Comment: Dont want it to be tampered so i thought it would be better if i added a hash and previous hash of the block.

Comment: The whole point of using a blockchain is that no one can tamper with the data stored within. (You may want to modify your smart contract to only allow certain accounts to store data, but once the contract is deployed, no one can change its code, and only it can control what data it stores.)

Comment: Which blockchain are we talking about? I know Solidity runs on Ethereum, but is a sidechain, what is the L2, is it private implementation (not common but still possible), etc.?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use a `mapping` for your case, cause this gives you the possibility to define a custom `index` which could be not just `0, 1, 2, ..., n`, but also a string or whatever you want. Here is an example:

```js
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract database{
        
    struct Table{
        uint value1;
        uint value2;
    }
        
    mapping(bytes32 => Table) public tables; 
    
    function addData(bytes32 _index, uint _value1, uint _value2) public {
        tables[_index].value1 = _value1;
        tables[_index].value2 = _value2;
    }
}
```

You could also use this expression to store the data via the `addData` function:

```js
tables[_index] = Table(_value1, _value2);
```

It looks better, but makes the size of the smart contract bigger!

Comment: in your example, are you using a bytes32 data type to index your mapping hence mapping(bytes32 => Table) public tables?

Comment: Yes. Imagine you have order names which you have to use. You just do: `tables['orderName12345']` and it shows you the order. Of course you pass the string as bytes32.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can simply *store data* in the blockchain as simple as that.

Let's say you deployed this contract to the network and the contract address is `0x1234abc...`.
Now you deploy it again, this time contract being deployed at `0x987cba...`
Calling `AddData()` on `0x1234abc...` and `0x987cba...` won't be the same.
You're simply adding more data to `that specific instance` of that contract.

I can't say if storing some data in this way would be safe, It can be as safe as you want it to be. Meaning, it depends on your specific need and implementation.

Currently your contract looks like it can never be tampered with.
Because you're only appending data, ***not*** modifying anything in the contract.

If you want your data to be modified you can add some kind modifiers to your `AddData()` function such as [Ownable by OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol). So the only owner can modify data in this contract.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code is

> correct

to store data in the blockchain using Solidity. It is safe to store data in the blockchain since it is decentralized, meaning it is not controlled by a single entity. However, you should be aware that storing data in the blockchain can be expensive, so it's important to consider the cost when designing your DApp.

Comment: This looks like ChatGPT output, which is banned on Stack Overflow.